# Wildflyのstandalone.xmlでデータソースのパスワードを暗号化したい

Tags: java, wildfly

Wildflyのstandalone.xmlに、データソースへの接続情報がありますが、ここにはDBのユーザパスワードが平文のまま書かれています。
これを暗号化（standalone.xmlをテキストエディタで開いても平文が分からない状態に）したいのですが、方法はありますか？

Wildflyではできないが、JBossEAPならできる、という情報でも助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

方法はあります。

以下WildFly 10.0.0で検証した結果を記載します。
デフォルトのstandalone.xmlにあったH2データベースのデータソースを対象にします。

まずパスワードを暗号化します。暗号化するためのライブラリが提供されています。
それを使いパスワードを暗号化します。ここではパスワード文字列は"sa"

```
$ java -cp /usr/local/opt/wildfly-as/libexec/modules/system/layers/base/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-4.9.4.Final.jar:/usr/local/opt/wildfly-as/libexec/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logging/main/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule sa       
Encoded password: 9fdd42c2a7390d3
```

私はWildFlyを`/usr/local/opt/wildfly-as/libexec`ディレクトリにインストールしています。ここを実際にインストールしたディレクトリに書き換えてください。

暗号化したパスワード`9fdd42c2a7390d3`を使いstandalone.xmlを変更します。
以下の行を追加します。

```
        <security-domains>
            ...(中略)
            <security-domain name="EncryptedPassword">
              <authentication>
                <login-module code="org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
                  <module-option name="username" value="sa"/>
                  <module-option name="password" value="9fdd42c2a7390d3"/>
                  <module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName" value="jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=dwh"/>
                </login-module>
              </authentication>
            </security-domain>                
        </security-domains>
```

name="username"の値は、実際のユーザ名に書き換えてください。name="password"の値を、先ほど暗号化した値に書き換えます。

さらに、以下の行を変更します。

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

要素の部分を次のように変更します。

```
                <security>
                    <security-domain>EncryptedPassword</security-domain>                      
                </security>
```

これで、`<security-domain name="EncryptedPassword">`のユーザ名とパスワードを使用します。

最後に、接続確認をします。

```
$ ./standalone.sh

$ ./jboss-cli.sh
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources:read-resource(recursive=true)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "data-source" => {"ExampleDS" => {
            "allocation-retry" => undefined,
...（中略）...
        }},
        "jdbc-driver" => {"h2" => {
            "deployment-name" => undefined,
            "driver-class-name" => undefined,
            "driver-datasource-class-name" => undefined,
            "driver-major-version" => undefined,
            "driver-minor-version" => undefined,
            "driver-module-name" => "com.h2database.h2",
            "driver-name" => "h2",
            "driver-xa-datasource-class-name" => "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource",
            "jdbc-compliant" => undefined,
            "module-slot" => undefined,
            "profile" => undefined,
            "xa-datasource-class" => undefined
        }},
        "xa-data-source" => undefined
    }
}
```

ここでのデータソース名は`ExampleDS`です。このデータソースにテスト接続します。

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS:test-connection-in-pool
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [true]
}
```

接続できました。

なお、こちらを参考に、私の方で実際に検証しました。
[jboss7.x - WildFly datasource password protection - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731694/wildfly-datasource-password-protection)